# How to make redirect rewrite rule for https subdomain on apache (CentOS8)?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, subdomain

I have own domain for example.

```
https://example.com
```

Below is my apache virtual host with 301 redirect rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName example.com 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public 
 <Directory /var/www/html/example> 
   AllowOverride All 
 </Directory> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

I can only access `https://example.com` but not for `https://subdomain.example.com`. The 'Not Secure' alert. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You need a certificate for subdomain.example.com. This has nothing to do with the redirect.

Comment: Dear Gerald Schneider, Thanks. btw, could you pls advise how to add subdomain in virtual host? Do I need another virtual host separate from main domain.

Comment: If you have the certificate for the subdomain in a separate file or it should deliver other content than the main domain then you need another VirtualHost for it. Otherwise you can just add it as an alias to the existing VirtualHost.

Comment: Dear Gerald Schneider, Thank you very much. I'll try it out.